# Как обновить ячейку DataTable

Tags: c#

Есть *DataTable*, который представляет из себя таблицу из 2 колонок: *ИД* и *Наименование товара*. Подскажите, каким образом организовать обновление наименования товара в *DataTable* по ИД?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DataTable dt = GetData();
int filterID = getFilterID();
dt.AsEnumerable().Where(p => Convert.ToInt32(p["ИД"]) == filterID ).ToList().ForEach(
    k =>
    {
       k.BeginEdit();
       k["Наименование_товара"] = somevalue();
       k.EndEdit();
    });
```

Comment: Спасибо, это то, что нужно.